# Set target directory in RPM spec file

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a very simple tar.gz file wih Java files which I want to install using RPM package. I created this spec file:

```
Name:           test
Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        test installation script

Group:          Utilities
License:        GPL
URL:            http://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/linux-build-simple-rpm-packages.php
Source0:        test-1.0.tar.gz
BuildArch:      x86_64
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)

#BuildRequires:  
#Requires:       

%description
test installation script

%prep
%setup -c /opt/test


%build
#%%configure
#make %{?_smp_mflags}


%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
#make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

#install -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/agent


%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc

%changelog
```

It's not very clear how I can configure the target directory where the target files should be extracted. Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: The `URL` tag is generally used (see the [Fedora wiki RPM docs](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#SPEC_file_overview) for the URL of the project being packaged (not the URL of a page about building RPM packages). That's an "error" in that guide.

Answer (score 2):

The build process of an RPM package should operate **entirely** within the build directories and should **not** touch the host system in any way.

So `%setup -c /opt/test` is incorrect as is creates a directory in the host system. Instead you should likely simply use `%setup -q` and let the default macro extract your source tarball in the default build directory. (If your tarball does not contain a toplevel directory, that is it is a "tar-bomb", then you can use the `-c` flag with a relative path to create as the toplevel directory in the current directory.

If you don't have any sources to build then you don't need a `%build` section at all.

The `%install` section is intended to copy files from the local build directory to the final directory under the buildroot. So (as in that linked guide) it should copy files to `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/test` or whatever other path under `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` is appropriate.

Those paths (without the `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` prefix) are then what need to get listed in the `%files` section.

The Fedora project has [some](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) [documentation](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/) on building RPMs that will likely be useful to you. The [Maximum RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/) book, while very old and somewhat out-of-date, is still a good source of information as well.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer already explained the problem with the %setup -c command, and the general principles of building RPMs.

I'll add the following, which may help you understand how the RPM build script should work:

```
%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
#make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

The above snippet, from the skeleton spec file, gives you a big clue. What you should be doing here is creating an installation image under $RPM_BUILD_ROOT.

So, if you want to, for example, install files in /opt/test, you'd probably want to do something like:

```
%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/test/bin
cp <something> $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/test/bin/something
```

The RPM build script is supposed to create what essentially is an installation image under $RPM_BUILD_ROOT. rpm then packages it up, and produces the binary installable rpm file that installs the contents of $RPM_BUILD_ROOT.

You will also need to have a %files section that lists all the individual files that get installed, as a sanity check. rpm will package only the files listed there in $RPM_BUILD_ROOT.

So, your general guidelines are:

- In the setup section, extract your tarball into the current working directory. rpm creates a scratch directory for the build. %setup, by default, will unpack the files in there.
- In the install section, copy what you want from the current working directory to $RPM_BUILD_ROOT. This becomes the installation image.

Comment: Thank you. I was reading mans/books trying to understand the relation between (flies listing/build_root structure/installation dirs) and in all those resources it wasn't clearly stated what is going on. Saying "image under $RPM_BUILD_ROOT" was what made me understand.